# Proof of Urysohn's lemma (or what my teacher called with that name)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In class, I have been given the following statement.

**Urysohn's lemma**

Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hasudorff topological space and $K\subseteq V\subseteq X$ are respectively a compact and an open set. The there exists a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f\equiv0$ outside $V$ and $f\equiv1$ on $K$.

Having never seen this, I googled for a proof, and found [this](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~jsimon/COURSES/M132Fall07/UrysohnLemma_v5.pdf). So I looked for something proving LCH implies normal. Unfortunately, it seems [this does not hold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53300/locally-compact-hausdorff-space-that-is-not-normal). So how do I prove the above statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y=X\cup\{\infty\}$ be the $1$-point compactification of $X$, and apply the usual Urysohn's lemma on $Y$ to $K$ and $Y\setminus V$.  Since $K$ is not just closed but compact, it is still closed in $Y$.

Comment: And [this](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Hausdorff_implies_normal) proves compact Hausdorff implies normal. As for the 1-point compactification, I luckily already knew about it. I'm sure there is something around the web about it, but won't bother searching.